# WordPress .htaccess Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I normally wouldn't post on here and try to figure things out myself but I'm at my wits end.

I'm trying to perform a redirect in WordPress so that requests to:

```
/property/123-my-unique-uri-here
```

... get forwarded onto a file called `/property-details.php` but the URL remains the same in the address bar.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/Divi/property-details.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, when I visit the URL `/property/123-my-unique-uri-here` I just got forwarded to the homepage.

If anyone has any ideas at all I'd be eternally grateful!

Comment: There must be other rules, like the standard WP rewrite to index.php, maybe more. Order is also relevant.

Comment: Use the Wordpress rewrite rule function https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: For ref, if you don't get the answer you want here, there is also a dedicated wordpress.stackexchange.com site that might be able to help you.

Comment: I've made sure it's the first rule in the .htaccess, and I've also tried the add_rewrite_rule option. Like you, I suspected something else must be going on, I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^property/123-my-unique-uri-here$ /property-details.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Another option is to just use a 301:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /property/123-my-unique-uri-here(.*) /property-details.php$1
```